# How do I reject a non-int and a negative number in the same line of code? c#

Tags: c#

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of items purchased");
 while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemQuantity)) 
 Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a valid non-negative number.");
```

In the while statement, I want to be able to reject a non-integer and a negative number to display the error message.

Comment: Readabiltiy should have a higher priority then shortness. At least for me. Squeezing 3 operations into one line will only result in you not being able to debug from **where** an exception is comming. Indeed I lost count how often "split it into seperate lines" was the first debugging step here :) Also for console inputs I do prefer to use a do...while loop, rather then a while. That way you can make checks as complex as you like at the end of the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Layzoo. I too personally prefer readability, unless you are working on a monster application where performance is paramount. It's also easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `||` operator the `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemQuantity)` is determined before `itemQuantity < 0` so you have itemQuantity:

```
int itemQuantity = -1;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out itemQuantity) || itemQuantity < 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Error, enter a valid non-negative number.");
```